# Property visibility change in Three20

Tags: iphone, three20

I created an application with Three20 that was accepting into the app store two years ago.  When revisiting it recently, I found that self.originalNavigatorURL does not resolve from a component that implements an interface that descends from UIViewController.  I am not clear what's changed over the past couple of years.

Comment: I'm using Three20 version 1.05 and XCode 3.2.6

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you were using Three20 from a couple years ago, it was probably before we started cleaning up the library. Part of this cleanup involved making the Three20 additions an optional import into the library via `Three20+Additions.h`. You're probably using `Three20.h` right now, so if you switch that to `Three20+Additions.h` you'll get access to originalNavigatorURL and co.

Comment: Thanks featherless.  That was the issue.